# Why is my PIC not blinking its leds?

Tags: c++, embedded, pic, microchip

I am trying to get started with pic24's, specifically the PIC24FJ64GA002, and I have looked in the datasheet at the registers and whatnot, but I still cannot get it to blink the leds. When I run it via debug it runs correctly, but when I try to actually run it on the pic it seems to not run at all.

I am using an external Oscillator, a 8MHZ Oscillator specifically, connected to pins 9(OSCI) and 10 (OSCO). Compiler is C30 in Mplab.

Datasheet link is: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39881D.pdf

The code is below

```
//include basic header definition
#include <p24FJ64GA002.h>

//config
_CONFIG2(0x0200);
_CONFIG1(0x0800);

int i;

//main loop
int main(void)
{

   OSCCON = 0x2280;  //select external OSC, no PLL
   AD1PCFG      = 0xFFFF;  //set to all digital I/O
   TRISA = 0x0000;  //configure all PortA as output

   while(1)    //Loop forever
   {
  LATAbits.LATA0 = 1; //RA0 = 1
  Wait();
  LATAbits.LATA0 = 1; //RA0 = 1
  Wait(); 
   }

}


int Wait(void) // gives me a nice delay of 1/3rd a second or so
{
for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++)
 { 
  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for all your help, but it was that I set the config bits wrong, when I set them in the config editor in mplab all works well.

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: For the next poor soul who comes across this question with a similar issue, could you edit this questions and specify which config bit was incorrect and what value corrected the issue?

Answer (score 7):

You need to go hi, wait, then lo, wait... you are just going hi, wait, hi, wait.

```
   while(1)    //Loop forever
   {
  LATAbits.LATA0 = 1; //RA0 = 1
  Wait();
  LATAbits.LATA0 = 0; //RA0 = 1
  Wait(); 
   }
```

Comment: @Chubsdad Programming is logical by definition :)

Comment: Oh, that was a typo on my part, the actual code does does have the Latch change correct, from 0 to 1. Either way, the led does not actually turn on.                                                   I am thinking that I set some registers wrong somewhere, such as the config words or peripherals. I think that the ADC has been turned off correctly, only other things on those pins are the Vref and some interrupt.

Comment: You running the pic at 3v ?  Are you using a ~3v led ?  Do you have the anode connected to RA0  and the cathode connected to ground ?

Comment: Is MCLR floating ?  or disabled via config ?

Comment: Also I think you want to change your LATAbits.LATA0 to PORTAbits.RA0=1 / 1... and put one LATAbits.LATA0 = 0 before the while near setting the tris

Comment: Target power not detected - Powering from PICkit 2 ( 3.50V)
PIC24FJ64GA002 found (Rev 0x3043) From mplab,it is running at 3.5v, callibrated yesterday just incase. It is a led made for 5v, but if it is driven at 3v, shouldn't it still light up, at least dimly? Thank you for helping me btw :D

Comment: depends on the minimum forward voltage of the led, grab a cheapy low power led to be safe.

Comment: I normally use CCS compiler not mplab which its a little different.  Try Changing LATAbits.LATA0 to PORTAbits.RA0 and add a single LATAbits.LATA0 = 0 under the tris statement

Answer (score 0):

What optimization level are you compiling with?  If it's only working in debug, it's possible the optimizer is reducing the whole `Wait()` function to a no-op.   Try declaring `volatile int i'.